# How to exclude some rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an alternative to this code. I need to select all the rows with name "export 1" , "export 2" and so on excluding "export test"

```
Sub CopyManager()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim valsArray As Variant


     valsArray = Array("Export *") '<--| define your values to be filtered on Source sheet column A
    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")

    With Source  '<--| reference Source sheet
        With .Range("A1:A1000")  '<--| reference its range from A1 to A1000
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=valsArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues   '<--| filter referenced range on its first column with values stored in valsArray
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("A2") '<--|copy filtered cells skipping headers and paste in target sheet from cell A1
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("B2")
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

The above code will copy all the rows with name "export 1","export 2" and so on and also includes "export test "but i need to exclude "export test"

Comment: Just an idea: the expression `"Export *"` looks like a regular expression. What about `"Export [0-9]*"`, does that do the trick?

Comment: Export 1, Export 2 is just an example , it can be anything not just numbers

Comment: In that case, just add an extra condition to your `IF`-clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a second criteria in your Autofilter.
Change the operator to `=xlAnd`and add an excluding citeria with `<>`:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=valsArray, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Export test"
```

Obviously, you can have this criteria being a variable, just as the filter criteria if needed.

Comment: can i use both Operator:=xlFilterValues and Operator:=xlAnd ?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You can only use one Operator and two cases. One option could be filtering the result tab instead. By adding `Target.Range("A1:A1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Export test", Operator:=xlFilterValues` after the first `end with`

Comment: However, that's probably not what you want, as you will then copy the "tests" as well, and then just filter them out (hide them). What makes you need xlFilterValues? Worst case you can do it completely different without the use of AutoFilter.

Comment: what if i pass another value in Array ,e.g. Array("Export *","Download *"). 
So i need  **Operator:=xlFilterValues**

Comment: @Pavan You are limited to two criterias when using wildcards, so you'd have to use another method than just autofilter at that point I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

i not pretty sure but one possible solution is to

replace

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=valsArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

with:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Export Test*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: i need Operator:=xlFilterValues  , is there any way to use both ?